# SoapUI Load test groovy sequentially reading txt file

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using free version of soapui. In my load test, I want to read request field value from a text file. The file looks like following

```
0401108937
0401109140
0401109505
0401110330
0401111204
0401111468
0401111589
0401111729
0401111768
```

In load test, for each request I want to read this file sequentially. I am using the code mentioned in [Unique property per SoapUI request using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424797/unique-property-per-soapui-request-using-groovy) to read the file. How can I use the values from the file in a sequential manner?

I have following test setup script to read the file

```
def projectDir = context.expand('${projectDir}') + File.separator
def dataFile = "usernames.txt"

    try 
    {
        File file = new File(projectDir + dataFile)
        context.data = file.readLines()
        context.dataCount = context.data.size
        log.info "     data count" + context.dataCount
        context.index = 0; //index to read data array in sequence
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        testRunner.fail("Failed to load " + dataFile + " from project directory.")
        return
    }
```

In my test, I have following script as test step. I want to read the current index record from array and then increment the index value

```
def randUserAccount = context.data.get(context.index);
context.setProperty("randUserAccount", randUserAccount)
context.index = ((int)context.index) + 1;
```

But with this script, I always get 2nd record of the array. The index value is not incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the variable context.index to 0 and just do +1

You maybe need a loop to read all values.

something like this :

```
for(int i=0; i <context.data.size; i++){
    context.setProperty("randUserAccount", i);
    //your code
}
```

Comment: oh, i think you can choose the datasource step to read all values and put then in a variable and the loop step (you need Soapui Pro for these steps)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this setup script to the setup script section for load test and access the values in the groovy script test step using:

```
context.LoadTestContext.index =((int)context.LoadTestContext.index)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late reply but I was facing the same problem for my load testing for some time. Using index as global property solved the issue for me.

Index is set as -1 initially. The below code would increment the index by 1, set the incremented value as global property and then pick the context data for that index.

```
<confirmationNumber>${=com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue( "index", (com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue( "index" ).toLong()+1 ).toString()); return (context.data.get( (com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue( "index" )).toInteger())) }</confirmationNumber>
```